# Magnitude ratio fitting of a first order system with cftool

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the magnitude ratio of a first order system using cftool, I'm aware there are other ways to do that but I need to get to the solution through this method.

I have simulated an RC circuit and, after having applied a sine input at several frequencies, I have measured the output of the system;

[image: here is the circuit.]

Here are the vectors I have created in MATLAB with the data I have measured:

```
f = [1 10 100 120 130 150 160 170 1000 2000 3000 10000];
Vi = zeros(1,12);
Vi(1,:) = 1; %amplitude
Vo = [0.99 0.99 0.85 0.79 0.77 0.73 0.7 0.68 0.16 0.08 0.05 0.02]; %amplitudes
Vdb = 20*log10(Vo./Vi); %Vo converted to dB
```

Now, given that an RC circuit is a first order system, I know that the relationship beetween magnitude ratio and frequency can be written as:

```
M(omega) = 1/(sqrt(1 + (omega * tau)^2))
```

So, opening cftool in MATLAB, I have set:

```
X data: f
Y data: Vdb
Custom Equation: 1/sqrt(1 + (2*pi*a*x)^2) %omega = 2*pi*f
```

Using these settings, however, cftool doesn't plot what I expected to see, so I would like to figure out where my mistakes are.

Comment: Just checking, are `Vout` and `Vin` supposed to be the same as `Vo` and `Vi`?

Comment: @magnesium Yes, there were a couple typos, now it should be written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Y-data should be `V0`, not `Vdb`.

If you want the curvefit for the relationship between the voltage gain in dB and the frequency, then you need to alter the custom equation.

Comment: It looks like you are correct since, doing so, the time constant of the circuit matches the parameter a. That said, I would like to have the ratio in dB and the frequency on a logarithmic scale, however I'm not being able to get those.

Comment: You need to convert the equation so that it gives the correct relationship between frequency and the voltage gain in dB. Last I worked with logarithms was 10 years ago, but it might be enough to just do `log10(1/sqrt(1 + (2*pi*a*x)^2))`, though I'm not sure. That's more of a math/EE question though, not really MATLAB.

Comment: I've asked because I've already tried that equation and it looks like it doesn't work as it should. That said, I will accept the answer anyway, thank you.

Comment: `log10(1/sqrt(1 + (2*pi*a*x)^2))1` doesn't work, but `20*log10(1/sqrt(1 + (2*pi*a*x)^2))` does work. A slightly different/more generic approach would be to create another parameter and use this: `b*log10((1 + (2*pi*a*x)^2))`. The value I get for `b` is `-9.488`, which is close to `20*-(1/2)`, as expected.